# Error setting up initial repository in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: mysql, installation, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm setting up pentaho for the first time. It is able to see mysql but when I try and set up the initial repository it give me this error:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleAuthException: 
Incorrect password or login
```

Seems to want an admin (username) password.  Don't see anything about this in the docs and web searches have not been fruitful. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running Pentaho CE or Pentaho EE? How did you set up the PDI repository? You can run both Pentaho and Kettle without using a repository.

Comment: It is the general release v.6  New to Pentaho.  Some instructions I read said to set up repository.  I've not been able to set up a repository due to this login issue.  And if I don't need one I'll probably skip it.  Seems to connect to mysql just fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new `Kettle database repository` using MySql, you need to follow some setup instructions. You can try [these](http://edpflager.com/?p=1622), but they are for 5.x.

You can run all parts of PDI/Kettle without a repository. It just makes sharing your jobs and transformations with a group easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: DB User and Password are different than admin password. Note: The default password for the administrator is admin. Pentaho strongly recommends that you change this default password using the Repository Explorer or the Repository/Edit User menu. http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.01+Introduction+to+Spoon