# How can I create a Pentaho Data Integration repository in a sqlite3 database?

Tags: sqlite, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I wanted to create a repository to store transformations and jobs in it. I don't want to install a heavy weight RDBMS, and since Kettle/Spoon can deal with SQlite3 Databases I thought, I could use a SQlite3 Database.
So I created a new database file using the shell and I used the Repository Manager to create a new database connection to this new database file.

It worked, no problem. It also doesn't matter which user password combination I use: the test is successful.

[image: configuration of connection to sqlite database in kettle]

My connection details look like this:

[image: connection details shown in kettle]

All database tables seem to be in place:

[image: all tables in my sqlite database added by kettle]

But when I want to access the repository, I'm being asked for a password. I use admin:admin, but I'm getting this message:

[image: Cannot connect to repository in sqlite database]

I checked the `r_user` table in the database. I was considering, to change the password there, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35529914/1146700) that the default password is `admin`.

I was also thinking, that it's the database user and password that is required, but since it's a sqlite3 DB there is no such thing as a user and password to access it.

Anyone can help, please?

Comment: I'm using pentaho pdi 8.3 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit embarrassing, but I'm not sure for whom, but...

If you open up the `repositories.xml` in `.kettle` directory, you'll see this:

[image: Delete this Part and it'll work]

That's a version where I didn't supply a password for the DB User (not the repository user). In this case you see the text `Encrypted` in between the `<password>` tag. 
If you delete this text (leaving the `<password>` tag empty) the connection to the repository works (with user `admin` and password `admin` for the repository connection).

If you specified a password for the DB connection the encrypted password is stored in the `repositories.xml` file. But it's also prefixed with `Encrypted`. If you delete the prefix and leave the encrypted password intact it also works.
Since it's a sqlite3 database it doesn't matter what's the password, though.

Hope someone else will find this helpful.